# Reformat CSV file using awk

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I have a file like this -

```
 1,[test1] Joe,OK
 2,[test2] Jack,OK
 3,[test3] Tom,FAIL
```

I am printing the file like this -

```
cat file | awk -F"," '{ print "||"  $1 "||" $2 "||" $3 "||" }'
```

I would like the output file like this -

```
|| 1 || Joe  || OK ||
|| 2 || Jack || OK ||
|| 3 || Tom  || FAIL ||
```

i.e. `[test1] Joe` is modified to `Joe` how can we do something like this on each column.

```
echo "[test1] Joe" | sed 's/\[.*\]\s//g'
```

Which gives me only `Joe` how can I combined this with the other columns?

Comment: Does the input file really contain a leading space? I have a suspicion it's doesn't..

Answer (score 3):

In `awk` with the **correct** spacing:

```
$ awk -F, '{split($2,a," ");printf "||%s || %-4s || %s ||\n",$1,a[2],$3}' file
|| 1 || Joe  || OK ||
|| 2 || Jack || OK ||
|| 3 || Tom  || FAIL ||
```

You was almost there with your attempt, you should take a look at the `printf` and `split` functions.

Answer (score 2):

With sed:

```
   sed 's/\[[^]]*\]//;s/^/|| /;s/$/ ||/;s/,/ || /g' input
```

**Output**

```
|| 1 ||  Joe || OK ||
|| 2 ||  Jack || OK ||
|| 3 ||  Tom || FAIL ||
```

To do in-place start with `sed -i`

Comment: This doesn't add the field separator `||` to the start and end of each line.

Comment: Well it's as close Guru's and  sarathi I guess. `sed` probably isn't the best tool for this.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
awk -F, '{$1=OFS""$1;$NF=$NF""OFS;sub(/.* /,"",$2);}1' OFS=" || " file
```

On running the above:

```
 ||  1 || Joe || OK ||
 ||  2 || Jack || OK ||
 ||  3 || Tom || FAIL ||
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F"," '{gsub(/,\[.*?\]|,|^|$/," || ",$0) }1' your_file
```

or

```
perl -plne 's/^|,/ || /g;s/\[.*?\]//g' your_file
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp
1,[test1] Joe,OK
2,[test2] Jack,OK
3,[test3] Tom,FAIL
> perl -plne 's/^|,|$/ || /g;s/\[.*?\]//g' temp
 || 1 ||  Joe || OK || 
 || 2 ||  Jack || OK || 
 || 3 ||  Tom || FAIL ||
> awk -F"," '{gsub(/,\[.*?\]|,|^|$/," || ",$0) }1' temp
 || 1 ||  Joe || OK || 
 || 2 ||  Jack || OK || 
 || 3 ||  Tom || FAIL || 
>
```

If you want to replace the file inplace use:

```
perl -i -plne 's/^|,|$/ || /g;s/\[.*?\]//g' your_file
```

Comment: Missing the closing separator `||` and spacing is off.

Comment: Modified according to the comment.

Comment: Your attempted regex hacks still don't fix the spacing issue!

Comment: Ok @Sudo...you are the best.i am upvoting you.